# Handle large data with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am performing a calculation on large data set in mysql with laravel but it is making the page load very slow or sometimes server can't handle it. Is there any way to perform some calculation on a larger dataset. Can stored procedure or chunks will help to improve performance.

Comment: Yes. For any more specific answer you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: *some calculation* is a bit difficult to tell what this does and how it may be able to be improved.

Comment: Sometime your performance depend on logic code rather than large data ? So what is your calculation code look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details which kind of data you are dealing with .
for large data set you need to chunk them and perform calculation and group them up is good way because of you use big data set it will definitely increase time and load for operations.